# Are DNS requests from Tor exit nodes a security risk?

Tags: networking, security, monitoring, tor

I am monitoring network alerts using Security Onion. I have come across an IP, `109.163.234.2`, that is a known Tor Relay/Router. It is querying my DNS server for records. Are any bad actors trying to do anything bad?

Comment: Concern in what way?  Is your concern that if someone is using tor they are more likely to be a bad actor, or is your question about the technical nature of tor?

Comment: Apologies for the delay. My concern is that they are more likely a bad actor. Why would someone try to remain anonymous when browsing to an ecommerce retail site?

Comment: You are making the assumption that they choose which sites to route through tor and which ones to go direct.  Many people set up tor and route everything through it.

Comment: Why would someone try to remain anonymous when browsing to an ecommerce retail site?  Because they don't think it's any business of yours (or your advertisers) to know who exactly they are, or where they're from, just because they want to check out your site.

Answer (score 2):

That's normal. As written in [this Tor.SE answer](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/8/how-does-tor-route-dns-requests), people using Tor don't resolve hostnames themselves, since that would compromise their anonymity. The Tor exit node does the resolution so the DNS server operator can't know who's asking for what.

I wouldn't worry about it unless there's actual exploit code hitting up your server. If you're really concerned, you can try to block Tor exit nodes, but people could always use other means of anonymizing if they wanted to do harm to your server.

Getting queried is part of being on the public Internet. Tor users need DNS too.